# Deserializing a double throws exception on mono

Tags: c#, mono, json.net

I have this piece of JSON (actually I have a much larger piece of JSON, but this is enough to provoke the exception):

```
{'something': 0.0}
```

I then try to deserialize this using either JsonConvert.DeserializeObject or JObject.Parse:

```
var result = JObject.Parse("{'something': 0.0}");
```

This works fine on my development machine running Windows, but it throws an exception when I run it on my Raspbian Pi using mono:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
  at System.Double.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Double.Parse (System.String s, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Convert.ToDouble (System.String value, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadContentFrom (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader r) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer.ReadTokenFrom (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse (System.String json) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Tstat.Mono.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I tried changing the culture for the thread, but that did not have any effect.

Is this a bug in JSON.NET, or am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

Some versioning information. I built mono from source, so I have this version of mono running:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 3.4.0 (master/89684c5 Thu Feb 27 14:37:23 UTC 2014)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       normal
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  armel,vfp+hard
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug 
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

JSON.NET is version 5.0.8 (assembly version 4.5.0)

Comment: Which version of JSON.NET?

Comment: The assembly version is 4.5.0, the NuGet package version is 5.0.8

Comment: 'k, there was a [bug fix in JSON.NET 4 release 4](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2011/11/19/json-net-4-0-release-4-bug-fixes) related to invariantculture that could have fixed your problem. `Change - JsonTextReader.Culture is now CultureInfo.InvariantCulture by default`. I guess that's not your problem then :)

Comment: Nope, it does not appear so, but thank you for your input anyway!

Comment: file a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/